# Columns auto selecting

Tags: mysql, procedure, transpose

In my fluid structure I have this raw results:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Results                                                              |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | group_id | question_id | question | answer_id | answer | input  |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | 10001    | 1           | How old  | 1         | 25     | NULL   |  
| 2  | 10001    | 2           | What like| 3         | Cola   | NULL   |
| 3  | 10001    | 2           | What like| 4         | Other  | HotDog |
| 4  | 10001    | 3           | City     | 5         | NYC    | NULL   |
| 5  | 10001    | 4           | Name     | 7         | Other  | Alex   |
| 6  | 10002    | 1           | How old  | 1         | 25     | NULL   | 
| 7  | 10002    | 2           | What like| 6         | Candy  | NULL   |
| 8  | 10002    | 3           | City     | 8         | LA     | NULL   | 
| 9  | 10002    | 4           | Name     | 7         | Other  | Roman  | 
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

After transform:

```
SET @i := 1;
    SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS `id`, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'How old' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS `How Old`, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'What like' THEN IF(answer='Other', input, answer) ELSE NULL END) AS `What like`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'City' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS `City`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'Name' THEN IF(answer='Other', input, NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS `Name` 
    FROM theTable
    GROUP BY group_id;
```

I have this table:

```
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id | How Old  |  What like  | City     |  Name     |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 25       | Cola,HotDog | NYC      | Alex      |
| 2  | 25       | Candy       | LA       | Roman     |  
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

It is example query, but real query with normal row ids link - works perfectly. But, i have different count of questions with some typical answer variant in other quiez.

What I can put switch of this rules:

```
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'How old' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS `How Old`, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'What like' THEN IF(answer='Other', input, answer) ELSE NULL END) AS `What like`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'City' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS `City`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'Name' THEN IF(answer='Other', input, NULL) ELSE NULL END) AS `Name`
```

to MySQL cycle or procedure in top answer like as https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql?

p.s.
Also, I can prepare "select" in PHP, but its too simple =)

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Look to GROUP_CONCATs, there are differents. Need automated building "select statements" with GROUP_CONCAT by answer='Other'